# Arithmetic background of this RNG code

Tags: modular-arithmetic, finite-fields, random, cryptography

I am trying to figure out the mathematical background of the random number generation of an old video game. It does iterations where it updates a 33-bit state consisting of the variables z (32-bit) and some flag f (1-bit). It generates a 'random' 8-bit value per iteration by just taking the lowest byte of z. This is the algorithm in C++ style pseudocode:

```
    unsigned int z = SOME_SEED; // state variable
    unsigned int f = 0;         // LSB of previous state z
    unsigned int t;             // temp variable

    while(someRunningCondition)
    {
        t = ((z >> 1) + (f << 31)) ^ (z << 12);
        f = z & 1;
        z = t ^ (t >> 20);

        outputRandomValue(z & 0xFF);
    }
```

The iteration visits every state other than z = 0, f = 0 and thus has a period of $2^{33}-1$ and the random samples have uniform distribution. The code looks similar to efficient implementations of finite field multiplication in cryptography, but I am too inexperienced in the topic to figure it out myself. If someone could break down the math underlying this code for me, that would be great.

Comment: Your guess is probably right. Too late an hour for me to wrap my head around the snippet.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Sounds promising. What confuses me is that $2^{33}-1$ is not (Mersenne) prime.

Comment: @GDumphart: do I understand correctly that results of your numerical experiments imply that our operator has the order $2^{33}−1$ in **GL**? (i.e. it’s the *least* power of our operator that equals to identical operator).

Comment: @IncnisMrsi Yes, and this short program should confirm it: http://pastebin.com/cSMNryiq (terminated in ~20 seconds for me iirc). Sorry for being a bit vague, I did this test half a year ago.

Comment: GDumphart: you seemingly provided a non-portable code (I mitigated converting it to plain old C). The same result, yes. I proved it’s a multiplication in a ring, whereas your experiment shows that all ring elements but 0 are units, that indicates it’s **a field.** Expect to earn rₑp50 from you anyway ☺

Comment: @IncnisMrsi I don't quite understand, my algebra is very rusty. Did I provide wrong/contradicting information? Is your big answer valid nevertheless? Don't worry, you'll get the bounty :) About the code: Compiled on the very standard g++ for me.

Comment: The only gap in my answer was uncertainty about the nature of the quotient ring, whether is it a field. We proved numerically that can iterate this multiplication operation to obtain *any* element. Hence, all elements are multiples of *any non-zero element.* In other words, our ring is a field.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi Ok great, awarding the bounty now, thank you for everything! If you could incorporate those additional field-insights in your answer, so that everything is collected nicely, that'd be amazing. I didn't find the time yet to study your findings, but I am very much looking forward to it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether 2<sup>*n*</sup> − 1 is prime isn’t very important if we look for multiplication by certain constant in **F**<sub>2<sup>*n*</sup></sub> . Multiplicative groups of finite fields are always cyclic, and *any* cyclic group has elements of the full order, prime or composite. As follows from inspection the code, mathematics of this example is iteration of a linear operator on 33-dimensional vector space over **F**<sub>2</sub> . The only dubious fragment `(z >> 1) + (f << 31)` reveals addition modulo 2 as well, because the former term has most significant bit zero, whereas the latter has zeros anywhere but in the MSB. As any field extension, **F**<sub>2<sup>33</sup></sub> is isomorphic to a vector space, but to find a multiplication in this operator we must *specify* an isomorphism, i.e. specify how is **F**<sub>2<sup>33</sup></sub> encoded with these `z` and `f`.

We demonstrated it encode a multiplication in **F**<sub>2<sup>33</sup></sub> as follows. First, one observation:

> `t` = … `(z >> 1)` … `^ (z << 12);`
>    relative offset is 13 positions.
>
> `z = t ^ (t >> 20);` relative offset is 20 positions.

But 13 + 20 = 33. There is well-known representation of **F**<sub>*p<sup>n</sup>*</sub> (*p* = 2, *n* = 33 in our case) as a quotient ring of polynomials over **F**<sub>*p*</sub> over the ideal generated by some irreducible polynomial of degree *n*; we need to guess the ideal and the factor (multiplication to which does the operator represent).

Matrix of the operator that transforms `f` and `z` on each iteration in coordinates (`f`, `z`<sub>MSB</sub>, … , `z`<sub>LSB</sub>) is:

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
   1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
   1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0

Bands of ones progressing right-downwards are evident. We also see, when such band wraps over the right boundary, it starts

1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 …

on the left side, and nothing more is created there. Transpose of this matrix is multiplication by *X*<sup>32</sup> in the quotient ring **F**<sub>2</sub>[*X*]/〈*X*<sup>33</sup> − *X*<sup>13</sup> − 1〉 in the standard basis (from 1 to *X*<sup>32</sup>).

> Added on original poster’s insistence:
>   Why is **F**<sub>2</sub>[*X*]/〈*X*<sup>33</sup> − *X*<sup>13</sup> − 1〉 isomorphic to **F**<sub>2<sup>33</sup></sub>? Because we can prove *numerically* that order of multiplication-by-*X*<sup>32</sup> operator is 2<sup>33</sup> − 1, hence *any* non-zero element of the quotient ring is a power of *X*<sup>32</sup>. It implies that the ring is a field and *X*<sup>32</sup> generates its multiplicative group. There is only one field, up to isomorphism, with given finite number of elements.

Namely:

*X*<sup>0</sup> × *X*<sup>32</sup> = *X*<sup>32</sup> (1st row shown above; corresponds to `f = z & 1`)
 *X*<sup>1</sup> × *X*<sup>32</sup> ≡ *X*<sup>13</sup> + *X*<sup>0</sup> (2nd row shown above; expression for MSB of `z`)
 *X*<sup>2</sup> × *X*<sup>32</sup> ≡ *X*<sup>14</sup> + *X*<sup>1</sup> (3rd row shown above)
   ⋮
 *X*<sup>20</sup> × *X*<sup>32</sup> ≡ *X*<sup>32</sup> + *X*<sup>19</sup>
 *X*<sup>21</sup> × *X*<sup>32</sup> ≡ *X*<sup>20</sup> + *X*<sup>13</sup> + *X*<sup>0</sup>
   ⋮

Then, what means the **transpose** clause? It means that elements of **F**<sub>2<sup>33</sup></sub> are not 33-bit (`f`, `z`) vectors (the state), but **F**<sub>2</sub>-linear *functionals* on them. For example, `z & 0xFF` can be thought of as eight bit functionals on the state. Multiplication by *X*<sup>32</sup> iterates these functionals, that are then applied to initial seed. Behaves similarly stochastic; a mathematical difference there is, but a practical difference there is not.

Does it mean this operator isn’t a *direct* representation of some multiplication in **F**<sub>2<sup>33</sup></sub> ? Of course, not. To obtain a matrix with the same structure of columns (instead of rows) we can just permute the basis. Namely, let’s write it in coordinates starting from 12th bit of `z` (the coefficient at 2<sup>20</sup> in `unsigned int`), then counting 11th, 10th, 9th… bits of `z` up to MSB, then `f`, then 32th bit of `z`, and so on. Then, we see exactly transpose of the original matrix.
IMHO all such transposes of multiplications, in all finite fields, are “the same” (i.e. same conjugacy class in GL<sub>*n*</sub>(**F**<sub>*p*</sub>)) as operators of (possibly *other*) multiplications in the same field, but I’m reluctant to investigate.

Comment: Thank you, this is great so far. Don't worry, it's too late for serious math for me too. I'm eager to see what you're going to add and study your answer in detail. Good night!